# Sum of cells above the current one, including any rows inserted later

Tags: google-sheets

Now sure there may be better ways to do this but these are just questions of curiosity.

1. What is the placement of a cell itself called? Its address? Its placement?
2. Let's say I wanna add all the costs in D26 to D28 and show it in D29(total cell). I can just put in D29

   =SUM(D26:28)

but let's say I'm constantly adding rows above under D28 but before D29. So instead I wanna make it so that the total cell can self-identify itself, then find the cell right above it, then add everything from D26 to the cell above the total cell.

```
=SUM(D26:28)
```

That is basically what I am trying to achieve.

Please answer if possible in a way that works for google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done with

```
=sum(D26:indirect("D"&(Row()-1)))
```

where `indirect("D"&(Row()-1))` references the cell in column D with row number one less than the current row.

"D28" is called the address of a cell (in "A1 format", to be precise). The function `indirect` takes a string as its argument and returns the reference to the cell with the address given by that string.

Comment: Is there any way to do this such that if you add a new column before D, the formula doesn't get messed up (since the "D" is hardcoded in the indirect)?